# Why are my random numbers always the same?

Tags: random, fortran, gfortran

I'm using the `random_number` subroutine from Fortran, but in different runs of program the number which is being produced doesn't change. What should I include in my code so every time I compile and run the program the numbers change?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The random number generator produces pseudo-random numbers. To get different numbers each run, you need to initialise the [random seed](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html) at the start of your program. This picks a different starting position in the pseudo-random stream.

Comment: And the way to do that is to call RANDOM_SEED with no arguments. In most implementations this will "randomize" the seed.

Comment: @SteveLionel As the question is tagged gfortran, I'll note that this implementation appears not to be one of those.

Comment: @francescalus yes indeed that seems to be the case. I find that rather astonishing. The standard does say, though, that such a call initializes the seed in an "implementation-dependent" fashion, so what gfortran is doing is allowed by the standard. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html gives an example of how to randomize the seed, but... yuck.

Comment: This is not as bad as it seems. this "strange" behavior allows for sequences of random numbers to be the same from one run of your code to the next. this allows for easier testing for heavily stochastic systems. however, within the same program, the numbers are "random". if you want random numbers that are different from one run to another, then you use RANDOM_SEED. I find this to be a good implementation in general.

Answer (score 7):

The sequence of pseudorandom numbers coming from call(s) to `random_number` depends on the algorithm used by the processor and the value of the seed.

The initial value of the seed is processor dependent.  For some processors this seed value will be the same each time the program runs, and for some it will be different.  The first case gives a repeatable pseudorandom sequence and the second a non-repeatable sequence.

gfortran (before version 7) falls into this first category.  You will need to explicitly change the random seed if you wish to get non-repeatable sequences.

As stated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23875704) the intrinsic `random_seed` can be used to set the value of the seed and restart the pseudorandom generator.  Again, it is processor dependent what happens when the call is `call random_seed()` (that is, without a `put=` argument).  Some processors will restart the generator with a repeatable sequence, some won't.  gfortran (again, before version 7) is in the first category.

For processors where `call random_seed()` gives rise to a repeatable sequence an explicit run-time varying seed will be required to generate distinct sequences.  An example for those older gfortran versions can be found in [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html).

It should be noted that choosing a seed can be a complicated thing.  Not only will there be portability issues, but care may be required in ensuring that the generator is not restarted in a low entropy region.  For multi-image programs the user will have to work to have varying sequences across these images.

On a final note, Fortran 2018 introduced the standard intrinsic procedure `random_init`.  This handles both cases of selecting repeatability across invocations and distinctness over (coarray) images.

Comment: The link to the gcc documentation will also have to be updated, it should point to the older version as I did here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18773059/721644

Comment: Good point, thanks.  I assumed I did it correctly at the time, but it looks like I didn't.