# Monte Carlo using Fortran

Tags: fortran, montecarlo

I am attempting to do a Monte Carlo simulation using RANDOM_NUMBER. I am using gFortran. I want to perform the following:

1. Calculate monteNum (fixed number) and generate a random number, monteTest.
2. If monteNum >= monteTest, then generate another random number randPos which is used to select a row from an array.
3. Otherwise, generate a new monteTest until step 2 is satisfied.

Firstly, I tried to use a DO loop.

```
CALL RANDOM_SEED()
monteNum = (count_up + count_dn)/(nReal**2) ! This is just a number in [0,1].
DO i = 1, 100
  CALL RANDOM_NUMBER (monteTest) 
  ! monteTest is a randomly generated number used in Monte Carlo simulation
   IF (monteNum >= monteTest) THEN
    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER (randPos)   
     ! randPos will be used to select one flippable position randomly
    Vpos = INT(randPos*count)   
     ! position of the chosen vertex; count is the length of fList
    flipVertex(1,:) = fList(Vpos,:)
  ELSE
    i = i+1
  END IF
END DO
```

An error arises from the ELSE statement. Since it is not known that the IF statement will produce TRUE in 100 loops, I thought a DO WHILE was a better choice.

```
monteTest = 0.5 ! Setting the initial value. But ideally it should be random
DO WHILE (monteNum < monteTest)
  CALL RANDOM_NUMBER (monteTest) 
  CALL RANDOM_NUMBER (randPos)   
  Vpos = INT(randPos*count)   
  flipVertex(1,:) = fList(Vpos,:)
END DO
```

But it didn't work either. 
The problem is that `randPos` is always zero for initial `monteTest = 0.2` and `randPos = 5.35517931E-03` for initial `monteTest = 0.5`. Here, the correct value of `monteNum` is 0.22222.
I was expecting outputs to change every time I run it, but I am getting the same output every time. Why would that be? Am I using the `RANDOM_NUMBER` in a wrong way?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the error? What is the value of `monteNum`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23875589, and in particular, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875589/why-are-my-random-numbers-always-the-same/23875704#comment36828811_23875704.  That is, with gfortran `random_seed()` produces a repeatable harvest.

Comment: I used `random_seed()` but the output is still not changing..

Comment: You used `random_seed()`, yes.  But if you want to have different random number sequences with gfortran your call isn't sufficient.  You'll need to provide a different seed each time: `random_seed(put=seed)`.  You can find an example discusssed in the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Fortran it is forbidden to (try to) update the index variable inside a loop.  So the lines

```
DO i = 1, 100
   ...
  ELSE
    i = i+1
  END IF
```

won't compile.

As for your second snippet, I see no syntax errors, explain what you mean by *it didn't work*.