# Behaviour of random_number across different platforms

Tags: random, fortran, gfortran, random-seed

Here is a program I'm using to generate random numbers:

```f95
program randtest
    implicit none

    real rands(5)

    call random_number(rands)
    print*, rands

end program randtest
```

Note that I'm not initializing with a seed using `random_seed` as that is my intention. What I've learnt about pseudo-random number generators, like the one Fortran uses is that they start at a seed value which is either provided or chosen by default. So if the seed is not changed, the sequence of random numbers produced remains the same.

However, when I run this code on two different platforms using **gfortran**, I see different behaviour.

- On **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, gfortran 7.5.0**, it generates a different sequence of numbers each time I run the compiled code.
- On **Windows 10 (MinGW), gfortran 6.3.0**, it generates the same sequence no matter how many times I run it.

Any insight about why this happens? Is it because in Ubuntu, somehow a different seed is chosen by default on each run? If so, why, when both are compiled using **gfortran**?

Comment: The point of providing a seed is to make it reproducible. I am not sure why you would expect reproducibility in the absence of an explicit seed. "chosen by default" could depend upon the exact moment in time that the code is run.

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree, but why is the same sequence produced on Windows, then? I'm looking to find out the reasons for the difference, and why do I get such behaviour.

Comment: If it isn't explicitly documented, you would need to delve into the source of `gfortan` to see where the difference in behavior comes from.

Comment: @JohnColeman, [gfortran 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31922538/3157076).

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18880654/4996248 . If so, the problem (if it is an actual problem) is traceable to how `MinGW` approaches randomness.

Comment: I've suggested that this is a duplicate of another question.  That other question is _slightly_ different in its focus but the essential part is that: the behaviour is entirely implementation dependent, even depending on _versions_ of compilers used.  If you want to be consistent you need to code that explicitly. If you think that question doesn't help, please say so.

Comment: And if you do say so, you also have to provide the versions of gfortran, not just of the operating system.  francescalus already pointed out the change in how `random_seed()` without arguments works in different versions of gfortran. What happens if it is not called at all is implementation dependent but can easily depend on the version in a similar way.

Comment: @francescalus It helps get me an idea, thank you.

Comment: @francescalus Added. As you've explained, it is probably tied to the version of gfortran. I updated to MinGW gfortran 8.1.0 yesterday, and now the random number sequences are different each time.